# How to add a css class to this php code

Tags: php, wordpress

I am wondering how to add a css class to this part of the code which is linking to the older posts on a blog.

```
<?php posts_nav_link(' — ', __('« go back'), __('keep looking »')); ?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post what posts_nav_link looks like?

Comment: @ipman https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link

Comment: [There's no such thing as a CSS class](http://pumpula.net/p/apps/css-vocabulary/). Do you mean an HTML class? (I'm assuming that function outputs HTML). It would depend on what that function did.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:-

```
<div class="YOUR-CLASS">
<?php posts_nav_link(' — ', __('« go back'), __('keep looking »')); ?>
</div>
```

[See Documents Here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/posts_nav_link).

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

There's a jQuery way for issues like this, when you're not able to add classes to WP functions. Just add the class via jQuery:

**HTML**

```
<div class="navigation">
  <?php posts_nav_link(' — ', __('« go back'), __('keep looking »')); ?>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('.navigation a:first-child').addClass('your-class');
});
```

This will add a class to the first link in the div.

There's a **CSS** way as well without adding a class but properties:

```
.navigation a:first-child {
  /* your properties here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add css classes to the `<a>` tag generated by `posts_nav_link()` function, another way of doing it is using these hooks in your functions.php file

```
add_filter('next_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_nav_attributes');
add_filter('previous_posts_link_attributes', 'posts_nav_attributes');

function posts_nav_attributes() {
    return 'class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase"';
}
```

Read more of these here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/next_posts_link_attributes
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/previous_posts_link_attributes